# resize the content div based on the widow size and remaining elements will be remain same

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

There is three div on my page, which are aligned vertically. The first one is header, the second one is content and the last one is footer. Header and footer should be top and bottom respectively, even if I resize the window. But, the content size should be reszied based on the window size and it should be scrollable and need to see from top to bottom when scroll.

I have tried in the [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/dirihegopu/edit?html,css,output)

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  /* grid-template-rows: 1fr 5fr 1fr; */
}
.header {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.content {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  min-height: 20rem;
  max-height: 30rem;
  overflow: auto;
}

.footer {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

How to fix this issue.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What part has to be scrollable?

Comment: content div is crop some content when resize the window @Wimanicesir

Answer (score 0):

A method i used before would be something like this:

```
// adding tempate area so element positions become rigid
// adding overflow: hidden to hide default scroll
body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
    grid-template-areas: "header" "page" "footer";
    overflow: hidden;
}

// giving grid-area of each element
.header {
    grid-area: header;
}

// height: 100%; and overflow: auto; so page can scroll
.page {
    grid-area: page;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
.footer {
    grid-area: footer;
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do this without using grid-area and grid-template-areas?

Comment: Yes using `display: flex;` `flex-direction: column;`, and `flex-grow: 1` should have the same effect